# Trying To Print to PDF in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, pdf, prepress

I'm trying to set it up "with separate color layers (CMYK)" as the printer request, but the Mode is greyed out. I don't have an actual printer installed, and a PDF is the result  I want. I do have up to date Acrobat installed.

The Separations Preview shows up perfectly. Will saving from this method be sufficient?

[image]

Microsoft PDF is the only one that shows up. There's no Adobe option. I tried reinstalling Acrobat to see if it would add it, but no such luck.

Comment: Why would the printer request that, If I may ask?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use AdobePDF printer driver?

[image]

It seems to me that Microsoft's PDF driver simply can't separate.

Please note that the Adobe PDF Printer functionality to create PDF files is only available with Adobe Acrobat (paid version), and not with Adobe Reader (free version).

Answer (score 0):

On Macintosh if you do not have a postscript printer connected to your computer, you can still output separations using the ADPDF9.PPD (post script printer driver).  Instead of doing a Google search looking for this driver, I made it available for download here.. [ADPDF9.PPD](https://mega.nz/#!ftA2SYRI!mXc6IF-cHxg62eCJB8myZDIBqbFGf6WsEkwcHNeO8dw)

---

That PPD file needs to be placed in this folder
**/Applications/Adobe Illustrator CS6/Presets/PPD/**

Obviously my version of Adobe Illustrator is CS6 so that's what is in the file path.  Just find the same folder path for your version of illustrator.

---

Once you have copied that PPD file to that folder, you will then be able to use your separations output in the print dialog:

[image]
[image]